# Pressure level in central heating system

Tags: central-heating, boiler, water-pressure

Recently (since last week), the pressure in our heating system (as indicated by the pressure gauge on the boiler) is dropping rapidly.  We're having to top this up around once every two days.  As I understand it, this is caused by a leak somewhere in the system.

Are there any ways to identify where this leak may be.  I've been around all the radiators and visible pipes to check, and can't find anything.  Is it just a case of waiting until water starts dripping though the ceiling somewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could rent one of those infrared cameras from your local big box store.  Using this to look in the walls and ceilings might help in locating the leak, depending on how big of a leak it is.

Comment: Thanks for this - but I'm in the UK.  Does anyone know anywhere that rents these things out in the UK?

Comment: @pm_2 - You could always buy one.  They are expensive, but can be useful.  If you bought one you could rent it out to family and friends, or become a ghost hunter to recoup your investment.

Comment: I had a look online, they seem to be between £3 - 10K depending on what you get.  It's a little out of my budget!

Comment: @pm_2 - Another idea might be to call around to local building inspectors, you might be able to find one with an infrared camera who will come out and take a look for you (for a small fee of course).